# Install kaa single-node 0.10.0 or 0.11.0 on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: kaa

is Kaa single-node compatible with Ubuntu 18.10?

If i install on Ubuntu 16.04 it works, on Ubuntu 18.10 everything seems starting right but when i try connecting to http://localhost:8080/kaaAdmin it shows that "it couldn't connect to the page" (in Ubuntu 16.04 works). Is it a firewall problem?

I followed kaa installation guide (configuring zookeeper, mongodb etc)
Kaa's logs are empty (no errors, no warnings)...

I also tried compiling kaa 0.11.0 from source and this situation persists.

Greetigs,
kaa_newbie.

EDIT: It's a Zookeeper problem! Kaa works only on Zookeeper v3.4.8. If I install this version on Ubuntu 18.10, it works!

Answer (score 0):

It's a Zookeeper problem! Kaa works only on Zookeeper v3.4.8. If I install this version on Ubuntu 18.10, it works!